# Cocoa - Assign onClick event to NSMenu

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmenu

I want my status menu to call a function when it is clicked. What's the method that would let me assign that action? Something like this below but for the menu itself.

`NSMenuItem* item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" action:@selector(doX) keyEquivalent:@""];`

Comment: Can you explain little bit more? what do you need? on click event of the application menu? or something else?

Comment: My NSMenu has a Refresh menu item. When users click on the menu to expand it, the date it was last refreshed should change. I have a method `+(NSString *)formatRefreshDate` that should get called when menu is clicked...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hook into the menu opening event by setting your menu's delegate and implementing the protocol method `-[<NSMenuDelegate> menuWillOpen:]` in the delegate you designate.